# Bash script and escaping special characters in password

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a shell script which is trying to login into a box with password having special character.

```
sshpass  -p"\"$Passw\"" ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"${Hostname}"
```

I am passing Hostname and Password parameter from Jenkins. Password conatins $ characater for example n$1sachin .  But I am not able to login. Can anyone please help?

I tried different option but its not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have encounter similar problem, finally using `\` to escape special char in password is work for me, such as:

from `xxx)xxx#?xxx` to `xxx\)xxx\#\?xxx`

full command like this:

`sshpass -p xxx\)xxx\#\?xxx rsync -avzh ...`